# jQuery with Rails issue - datepicker()

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a rails application and I want to add the jQuery datepicker, to show when the user selects a field in a form.

The field is built using the following code:

```
<%= f.text_field :collection_date_time %>
```

Resulting in:

```
<input class="input-medium" id="pick_collection_date_time" name="pick[collection_date_time]" size="30" type="text" />
```

I have added the following to my `pick.js.coffee` file, but when I select the field, nothing happens.

```
$ -> $("#pick_collection_date_time").datepicker()
```

For info, I'm also using the twitter bootstrap framework (and the associated js).

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do in this case is open firbug or chrome inspector and check if he can find the file. Next check `development.log` if you see any problems with assets. Maybe you did a simple typo somewhere :)

Probably you need to go to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` and check if you have something like "//= require_tree ." if not add require for this file or you will have to go to `config/environments/<env>.rb` and add it to line `config.assets.precompile += %w( <name>.js )` so he will precompile with rest.

Comment: Thanks Jakub, I've just checked with a js debugger and am getting: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe you need lack jquery or some other dependency of datapicker. I'm like 99% sure its dependency problem.